# mpirun without options runs a program on one process only

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, gfortran, openmpi

[Here](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.10/man1/mpirun.1.php) I read

> If no value is provided for the number of copies to execute (i.e.,
>   neither the "-np" nor its synonyms are provided on the command line),
>   Open MPI will automatically execute a copy of the program on each
>   process slot (see below for description of a "process slot")

So I would expect

```
mpirun program
```

to run eight copies of the program (actually a simple hello world), since I have an Intel® Core™ i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz × 8, but it doesn't: it simply runs a single process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not specify the number of processes to be used, `mpirun` tries to obtain them from the (specified or) default host file. From the [corresponding section of the man page you linked](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.10/man1/mpirun.1.php#sect6):

> If the hostfile does not provide slots information, a default of 1 is assumed.

Since you did not modify this file (I assume), `mpirun` will use one slot only.

---

On my machine, the default host file is located in

```
/etc/openmpi-x86_64/openmpi-default-hostfile
```

Comment: This file on my machine is just comments. How should I modify it?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I never touched that file. If I need a custom hostfile, I create a new one. The syntax is described in the linked documentation.

Answer (score 1):

i7-2630QM is a 4-core CPU with two hardware threads per core. With computationally intensive programs, you should better start four MPI processes instead of eight.

Simply use `mpiexec -n 4 ...` as you do not need a hostfile for starting processes on the same node where `mpiexec` is executed.

Hostfiles are used when launching MPI processes on remote nodes. If you really need to create one, the following should do it:

```
hostname slots=4 max_slots=8
```

(replace `hostname` with the host name of the machine)

Run the program as

```
mpiexec -hostfile name_of_hostfile ...
```

`max_slots=8` allows you to oversubscribe the node with up to eight MPI processes if your MPI program can make use of the hyperthreading. You can also set the environment variable `OMPI_MCA_orte_default_hostfile` to the full path of the hostfile instead of explicitly passing it each and every time as a parameter to `mpiexec`.

If you happen to be using a distributed resource manager like Torque, LSF, SGE, etc., then, if properly compiled, Open MPI integrates with the environment and builds a host and slot list from the reservation automatically.

Comment: So is there no way to make `mpirun program` run as many processes as the numeber of cores (or threads)? This sounds strange to me, since on the mac I also use (2 x 3,2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Xeon), 8 processes are run if I do not specify the `-np` option. Where's the difference?

Comment: It depends on the MPI implementation and on any global or local settings. Perhaps the MPI library on that Mac system is specifically configured or it has a different MPI implementation installed. With Open MPI you can create your own default hostfile and set the environment variable `OMPI_MCA_orte_default_hostfile` to the full path of that file.